# Filtering Tuple in Swift

Tags: swift, uisearchdisplaycontroller, ios8

I have simple code:

```
var recipes = ["Shrimp with garlic", "Napoleon cake", "Beef steak"]
var searchResults = String[]()

func filterContentForSearchText (searchText: String) {
    searchResults = recipes.filter{ ($0 as NSString).localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("\(searchText)") }
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    self.filterContentForSearchText (searchString)
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView {
        return searchResults.count
    } else {
        return recipesDict.count
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SimpleTableCell") as? UITableViewCell

    if !cell {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "SimpleTableCell")
    }

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView {
        cell!.textLabel.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]
        cell!.image = UIImage(named: "food.jpg")
    } else {
        cell!.textLabel.text = recipes[indexPath.row]
        cell!.image = UIImage(named: "food.jpg")
    }
    return cell
}
```

It was work good. Table is full, table search works. Now I want to complicate the task:

```
var recipesDict = [(id: 1, name: "Shrimp with garlic", desc: "Lorem Ipsum....", time: 15, img: "shrimp.jpg"), 
(id: 2, name: "Napoleon cake", desc: "Lorem Ipsum....", time: 120, img: "napoleon.jpg"), 
(id: 3, name: "Beef steak", desc: "Lorem Ipsum....", time: 15, img: "steak.jpg")]
```

Change table functions:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView {
        return searchResults.count
    } else {
        // return recipes.count
        return recipesDict.count
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SimpleTableCell") as? UITableViewCell

    if !cell {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "SimpleTableCell")
    }

    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView {
        cell!.textLabel.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]
        cell!.image = UIImage(named: "food.jpg")
    } else {
        var currentRecipe = recipesDict[indexPath.row]
        NSLog ("Текущий рецепт : \(currentRecipe)")
        cell!.textLabel.text = currentRecipe.name
        cell!.image = UIImage(named: currentRecipe.img)
        // cell!.textLabel.text = recipes[indexPath.row]
        // cell!.image = UIImage(named: "food.jpg")
    }
    return cell
}
```

The table is still filled in correctly. Each row have your own image.I can't make filter for array of tuples. Can you suggest how I must modify the function filterContentForSearchText?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you re-write your question to more clearly indicate your problem? There is a while lot of unnecessary code here.

Comment: I think `$0.name` will do what you're looking for.  btw "\(searchText)" is identical to `searchText` since `searchText` is already a `String`

Comment: To get faster, better answers on SO, you should try to simplify your code example as much as possible so readers can easily see what's going on and try it out. All of the table code here is incidental to your question: all you really need is examples of the two data structures you're using and the call to `filter` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @JJSaccolo that these should be structs for better code clarity and type safety.

However, to answer your original question, you can use:

```
recipes.filter{ $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("\(searchText)") }
```

Comment: Yes! Working! Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Bill, where should i put "recipes.filter{ $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("\(searchText)") }"?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to don't save data in a Array in that way (using tuples), but using an appropriate way to represent your data: a `struct` or a `class`.

This is an example of what you should do with a class

```
class Recipe {
    var id = 0
    var name :NSString = ""
    var desc = ""
    var time = 0
    var img = ""

    init(id: Int, name: String, desc: String, time: Int, img: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.time = time
        self.img = img
    }
}


var recipes = Recipe[]()
var searchResults = Recipe[]()
recipes.append(Recipe(id: 1, name: "Shrimp with garlic", desc: "Lorem Ipsum...", time: 15, img: "shrimp.jpg"))
recipes.append(Recipe(id: 2, name: "Napoleon cake", desc: "Lorem Ipsum...", time: 120, img: "napoleon.jpg"))
recipes.append(Recipe(id: 3, name: "Beef steak", desc: "Lorem Ipsum...", time: 15, img: "steak.jpg"))

func filter (searchString: String) {
    searchResults = recipes.filter{ recipe in
        return (recipe.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("\(searchString)"))
    }
}
```